# How to iterate over Redis keys to get their values?

Tags: redis

How do I iterate over objects in Redis and get all their values? Something like this:

```
scan object* hgetall
```

This should return

```
age 22 password 1234 username Sarah
age 20 password 5678 username Mike
```

When Redis contains this data:

```
hmset objectSarah age 22 password 1234 username Sarah
hmset objectMike age 20 password 5678 username Mike
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with just one command, you'll need to scan and then process the results (i.e. `HGETALL` them) one by one.

You could, however, wrap this into a Lua script (see [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval)) that accepts the current cursor and fetches the data before returning everything to the client. I.e.:

```
local cur, pat = tonumber(ARGV[1]), ARGV[2]
local scan = redis.call('SCAN', cur, 'MATCH', pat)

for i, v in ipairs(scan[2]) do
  local data = redis.call('HGETALL', v)
  scan[2][i] = { v, data }
end

return scan
```

Runtime example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset objectSarah age 22 password 1234 username Sarah
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset objectMike age 20 password 5678 username Mike
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> script load "..."
"d81ace3345591b4fee7f3bf4cf28e7b260b59554"
127.0.0.1:6379> evalsha d81ace3345591b4fee7f3bf4cf28e7b260b59554 0 0 object*
1) "0"
2) 1) 1) "objectSarah"
      2) 1) "age"
         2) "22"
         3) "password"
         4) "1234"
         5) "username"
         6) "Sarah"
   2) 1) "objectMike"
      2) 1) "age"
         2) "20"
         3) "password"
         4) "5678"
         5) "username"
         6) "Mike"
```

Notes:

1. This is actually cluster-safe and the use of programmatically-generated key names here should be ok.
2. Be careful of `HGETALL` w/ big hashes.
3. Scanning is not recommended for big datasets and/or for providing fast responses